# Whether all apps require the database Connection?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating an app which doesn't take any data from the database. The content is not dynamic (ie.. it is static content ) and I am using 3 View, in each view I am displaying some content. That's why I am not using any database connectivity.

Whether all apps need DATABASE. Whether static data is accepted by APPLE PEOPLE.

Comment: i assumed iOS. and yes it is fine to have static data, its just if its a LOT of data it's probably preferred to be dynamic so you aren't storing all that data on the users phone needlessly.

Comment: Yes.Ok Cool, just using some words(100 to 120) and with 2 paragraphs in each View.Likewise I have 3 View.

Comment: I am Using NSMutableArray and [rowData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Achiever %C", 0xAE ]]; The above sentence I am using around 30 time(in RootViewController.m) to display the words  and if we click word(in TableView), we will move next view , here some content will display and again if we click on next view, here also some content will display and one button (if we click on it) we will move to next view.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need a database, no. Store your data however you want :)

Hoewver, unless it's only a fairly small set of data, a database might perform better? It entirely depends on what you app is going to be doing.

Comment: Yes.Ok Cool, just using some words(100 to 120) and with 2 paragraphs in each View.Likewise I have 3 View

Comment: I am Using NSMutableArray .[rowData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ABCXYZ %C", 0xAE ]];

Comment: I am Using NSMutableArray and [rowData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Achiever %C", 0xAE ]]; The above sentence I am using around 30 time(in RootViewController.m) to display the words  and if we click word(in TableView), we will move next view , here some content will display and again if we click on next view, here also some content will display and one button (if we click on it) we will move to next view.

Comment: That sounds like it's not much data at all - you almost certainly don't need a database :)

Comment: Sir, one more some issue in my app I am moving to left to Right(as it by default ) in UISwipeGesture, but any I am moving to RIght to left i am moving fine ,but the issue is in the Navigation Bar. The left side and Right side are showing wrongly. Did u get me? In this Function---> (void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer

Comment: Issue is coming when I am using swiping--> to move to Next View. With the help of BUTTON( ie.. W/O swiping) it is moving fine, but while using Swiping to move to next view or previous view (to and fro) is fine, but issue is in the Navigation bar( Arrow Shaped Button in the left side and Button in the right side). Please inform me, if you are not cleared with the Question?

Comment: I'd ask that as a new question - then you can add some code examples etc.

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative to using a database, or a remote web service, is .plist files.
They have a number of advantages, for instance they are loaded into memory very easily (2 lines):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *dataArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath] retain];
```

(or NSDictionary, if you're loading a dictionary instead of an array).

They are also edited easily in Xcode or using "Property List Editor" which is included with Xcode.

The downside of them is that the whole plist file is loaded into memory at once. If your plist file is larger than... say 500kb? I would consider moving to a db.

Comment: I am Using NSMutableArray and [rowData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Achiever %C", 0xAE ]]; The above sentence I am using around 30 time(in RootViewController.m) to display the words  and if we click word(in TableView), we will move next view , here some content will display and again if we click on next view, here also some content will display and one button (if we click on it) we will move to next view.

Comment: Any tutorial link on plist Concept?